# ASP.NET MVC Upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to create my first web application. Where I want users to be able to upload files. But all I get is a 404 ERROR when I go to http://localhost:64679/File/Index. I can't really see where the problem is:

Index.cshtml:

```
<h2>Basic File Upload</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload Files:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    <br><br>
    @ViewBag.Message
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace FileUploadApplication.Controllers
{
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        // GET: File
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                try
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"),
                                               Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is you GET method for `Index()` - all you have shown is the POST method

Comment: Do I need both GET and POST?

Comment: Yes (you cannot navigate to a page without a GET method)

Comment: And I can just add that method under the POST method, right?

Comment: Just add a method `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }`

Comment: Thank you! Works out perfect now

Comment: I think you have taken wrong controller name in action post method. rather use of HOME controller you should use "File" controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Index controller to load the page as shown below.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You need to add [HttpGet] attribute action method because you have already [HttpPost] .

Answer (score 0):

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<h2>Basic File Upload</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","File",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload Files:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    <br><br>
    @ViewBag.Message
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace FileUploadApplication.Controllers
    {
        public class FileController : Controller
        {

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    try
                    {
                        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"),
                                                   Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
                    }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
                }
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

You're code is perfect just need to replace Controller name while post a form from *.cshtml* file. So just replace that controller name with **FileController** you're issue will be resolved.

Add one get method as well. I already mentioned with same in example.

replace *Html.BeginForm("Index","**Home**",FormMethod.Post* with *Html.BeginForm("Index","**File**",FormMethod.Post*